# Wordpress site - adding alt attributes to existing images in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, hook, alt

I want to figure out how to add an alt attribute to pre-existing images on the site. I've read all the other posts I can find on StackOverflow and Wordpress.org, tested multiple functions, and haven't had much luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In my functions.php file, this function exists, but it doesn't appear to do anything.

```
    /* add alt attributes to all images */

        function isa_add_img_title( $attr, $attachment = null ) {

        $img_title = trim( strip_tags( $attachment->post_title ) );

        $attr['title'] = $img_title;
        $attr['alt'] = $img_title;

        return $attr;
            }
        
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes','isa_add_img_title', 10, 2 );
```

Here is a previous function I've also implemented with no effect.

```
function addImageAlt($attribute){
    $imgAttribute = trim( strip_tags($attribute->post_title) );
    $totalAttribute["alt"] = $imgAttribute;
    return $totalAttribute;
}
add_filter("wp_get_attachment_image", "addImageAlt", 10, 5);
```

Here is the template code, which is getting the image source

```
    {
        extract($atts);

        if (!is_front_page()):
            wp_enqueue_script('slick', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slick.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20160816', true);
            wp_enqueue_style('slick-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/slick.css');
        endif;

        $html = '<div class="brands-slider-wrapper">
                    <div class="brands-slider">';
                        $loop = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'zm_brands', 'posts_per_page' => $num_of_brands, 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'meta_value' ));

                        if ($loop && $loop->post_count > 0) :
                            while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                                
                                
                                $imgsrc=wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'brand-thumb');
                                $brand_thumbnail= $imgsrc[0] != "" ?  $imgsrc[0] : get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/default-music-icon.jpg';
                                $html.='<div class="slide-brand">
                                            <div class="brand-logo-thumbnail">
                                                <a href="'.get_permalink().'">
                                                    <img src='.$brand_thumbnail.' alt="'.basename($brand_thumbnail).'" title="'.get_the_title().'">
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>';
                            endwhile; 
                        endif;
        
        $html .='</div>
                </div>';
        wp_reset_query();
        return $html;
    }
```

The images for the sliders on the website appear to be sourced differently.

```
 $html .= '<div class="slide-instrument">
                                           <div class="instrument-category-thumbnail auto-height">
                                               <img src=' . $category_thumbnail . '" alt="' . $term->slug . '" title="' . $term->name . '">
                                           </div>
                                           <h4>' . $term->name . '</h4>
                                           <a href="' . get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy) . '"><span>View More</span></a>
                                       </div>';
```

Comment: how you have fetched the image is more important share the template file code sample with us so we can review it.

Comment: Hi Akshay, I've just uploaded the template code so you and others can have a look.

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: I'm no longer at work, but I will test it out next week and give you an update. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Hi Akshay, that seems to have worked for a large portion of the images on the site, but for the slider images, they seem to be sourced a little differently, so I'm not sure what to do for the slider images, I will edit the code into my original question.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, can you let me know that for slider  have you used any plugin or it is your custom code?

Comment: That's ok. I believe the slider is a plugin; the other developer and I found another PHP file with the shortcode for the slider. In the end, we have simply added some jquery to add an alt attribute for every image on the site. If you have a solution to do this through PHP, I'm still willing to give it a shot and would like to know what you think.

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by instead editing the application.js file, and adding this jquery function

```
$('img').attr('alt', function(){
    var src = this.src.split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
    return src;
});
```

This simply adds alt attributes to all images on the site, and is not necessarily the best way to do so, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `wp_get_attachment_image_src` to fetch the image and above filters are different.

`wp_get_attachment_image_src` : this has been used for the image url only.

`wp_get_attachment_image` : this has been used for the image url along with the img tag so if you are going to use `wp_get_attachment_image()` function then your filter will be going to work.

According to me, you need to change your template code like this :

```
$html.='<div class="slide-brand">
            <div class="brand-logo-thumbnail">
                <a href="'.get_permalink().'">
                    '.wp_get_attachment_image(get_the_ID()).'
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>';
```

I am assuming that you are geting the id in the `get_the_ID()`

I am assuming that your function is right with the filter.

Thanks